# How to normalize pixel values in an image and save it

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to normalize my data to prepare it as input for [this](https://tfhub.dev/google/aiy/vision/classifier/birds_V1/1) model. I tried following [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-manually-scale-image-pixel-data-for-deep-learning/) guide, but have been having issues.

First off, my min and max values aren't starting off as 0 and 255, and the final results are not normalized between 0 and 1.

Here is my function

```py
def process_image(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    new_image = image.resize((224,224))
    
    pixels = asarray(new_image)

    # confirm pixel range is 0-255
    print('Data Type: %s' % pixels.dtype)
    print('Min: %.3f, Max: %.3f' % (pixels.min(), pixels.max()))

    # convert from integers to floats
    pixels = pixels.astype('float32')

    # normalize to the range 0-1
    pixels /= 255.0

    # confirm the normalization
    print('Min: %.3f, Max: %.3f' % (pixels.min(), pixels.max()))
    new_image.save("result.jpg")
    
    return new_image
```

and here is my resulting output

```
Data Type: uint8
Min: 8.000, Max: 216.000
Min: 0.031, Max: 0.847
```

Any ideas why? And also, how can I save the image with these normalized results. As the code is written now, the pixels aren't being changed because I am only creating a copy of the pixels from new_image.

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

**UPDATED CODE**

Thanks to @relh for the help! I implemented his code and it runs great now

The code

```py
def process_image(image_path):
    min = sys.maxsize
    max = -sys.maxsize


    image = Image.open(image_path)
    new_image = image.resize((224,224))    
    np_image = asarray(image)
    if min > np_image.min():
        min = np_image.min()
    if max < np_image.max():
        max = np_image.max()    

    np_image = np_image.astype('float32')
    print("BEGINNING PIXEL VALUES", np_image)
    print('Data Type: %s' % np_image.dtype)
    print('Min: %.3f, Max: %.3f' % (np_image.min(), np_image.max()))
    np_image -= min
    np_image /= (max - min)

    print('Min: %.3f, Max: %.3f' % (np_image.min(), np_image.max()))
    print(np_image)
```

Output snippet

```
Min: 2.000, Max: 223.000
Min: 0.000, Max: 1.000

[[0.22171946 0.4162896  0.37104073]
  [0.23076923 0.42533937 0.3846154 ]
  [0.18099548 0.37556562 0.33484164]
  ...
  [0.12217195 0.51583713 0.47511312]
  [0.15837105 0.54751134 0.50678736]
  [0.16742082 0.5565611  0.51583713]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is calculate the real minimum and maximum values for your dataset, before doing your own minmax normalization.

Here's what that might look like:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image_paths = ['image_path1.jpg', 'image_path2.jpg', 'image_path3.jpg']
min = sys.maxsize
max = -sys.maxsize

for image_path in image_paths:
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    np_image = np.asarray(image)
    if min > np_image.min()
        min = np_image.min()
    if max < np_image.max()
        max = np_image.max()
```

This will give you the variables min and max and you can now use them to normalize between 0 and 1 with this instead of the /= 255 you had!

```
    ...
    pixels -= min
    pixels /= (max - min)
    ...
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hi @relh ! This worked great. I updated my answer accordingly. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Hi quick question. I was going through and updating my code to be able to iterate over multiple files, and changed up the code you gave a bit. I am wondering if the sys.maxsize code for the min max and the if statements are necessary. I took them out and just left min= np_image.min() and the same for max, and the normalization is working just fine, giving me values between 0 and 1.0 as the output. Can you explain why you included it?